# Backend code sending response to client side but not showing output of other lines in console log

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a backend code written on Node.js for my application. When I host my backend on a port, I am able to get the API response to my client side but outputs that should be displayed in console log(in Node) are not being displayed. I am assuming that when I run this code on my localhost port the entire code should be executed thus resulting in console log outputs (eg: "DB connected" should be displayed in console log). But this is not happening. Only the post request console log O/P is being displayed(i.e "response sent"). Why is this happening?

**Note:** The post request O/P is displayed only when I post to the backend. It is not being displayed by default which is the expected behaviour.

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import DB from "./env";
const app = express();
// DB connection

mongoose.connect(DB,{})
.then(() => {console.log("DB connected")})
.catch((error) => {error});
//middlewares

app.use(express.json({}));
app.use(cors({
    origin:["http://localhost:3000"],
}));

//the actual backend response from server

app.post("/" , (req,res) => {
   console.log("response sent");
   //console.log(req.body.email);
   //console.log(req.body);
   res.end("backnd working");
})

//listen on port 8000

app.listen(8000);
```

Comment: It's likely there's an error your code is `catch()`ing, but your callback doesn't do much with that error information. Add a `console.log()` or `console.error()` in your `.catch()` callback and see if you can get any useful information there.

Comment: I could be wrong, but what's going on with your CORS policy; also try send not end?

Comment: use Dotenv package to load environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things explained in comments so read it first.

```
// load environmental variables.
require("dotenv").config();
// require modules.
const express = require("express"),
      mongoose = require("mongoose"),
      cors = require("cors"),

// app contains all express stuff.
const app = express();

// showing ports of your app is dangerous.
// get port and host from .env file by using dotenv package.
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000,
      HOST = process.env.HOST || "localhost";

// you should use a seperate file to connect to database.
// here is the implementation of db.js file.
// anonymous function it will run automatically
(async () => {
  // try and catch block to handle error
  try{
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    console.log("Connection SuccessFull");
  }catch(err){
    console.log(`no connection due to: ${err}`);
  };
})();

// middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin:["http://localhost:3000"],
}));

// try to use express router in a seperate file for better consistency
// The home page api
app.post("/" , (req, res) => {
   console.log(`The home api hitted!
                Main data is ${req.body}`);

   res.status(200).send("backend working");
})

// listen app on given port and host
app.listen(PORT, HOST, (err) => {
  // if error occured then this will fire else log success message to console.
  if(err) console.log(err);
  console.log(`The app started successfully on http://${HOST}:${PORT}/`);
});
```

If something wrong then please tell me i will fix it.

I am not 100% sure that this will work!

Thank you!